# Where do tags save in acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, I'm trying to keep things simple here and do testing in the rails console.. However, I can't seem to figure out how to save tags and read them out again. As you can see from the paste below, I can't save the @consumer object (with tags) and then read out the tags..

http://pastebin.com/txpuf09g

```
1.9.3p286 :001 > @consumer = Consumer.first
Creating scope :page. Overwriting existing method Consumer.page.
  Consumer Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "consumers".* FROM "consumers" LIMIT 1
 => #<Consumer id: 29, hl: nil, created_at: "2012-10-27 23:27:15", updated_at: "2012-10-27 23:27:15", user_id: 33, display_name: nil, tagline: nil, desc: nil>
1.9.3p286 :002 > @consumer.tags
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 29 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND (taggings.context = 'tags')
 => []

1.9.3p286 :003 > @consumer.tag_list
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 29 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
 => []
1.9.3p286 :004 > @consumer.tag_list = "hi, ho"
 => "hi, ho"
1.9.3p286 :005 > @consumer
 => #<Consumer id: 29, hl: nil, created_at: "2012-10-27 23:27:15", updated_at: "2012-10-27 23:27:15", user_id: 33, display_name: nil, tagline: nil, desc: nil>
1.9.3p286 :006 > @consumer.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE "consumers" SET "updated_at" = '2013-02-15 00:25:05.187733' WHERE "consumers"."id" = 29
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (lower(name) = 'hi' OR lower(name) = 'ho')
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'hi' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "hi"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'ho' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "ho"]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 29 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE ("taggings"."tag_id" = 5 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = 29 AND "taggings"."context" = 'tags' AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("context", "created_at", "tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "tagger_id", "tagger_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["context", "tags"], ["created_at", Fri, 15 Feb 2013 00:25:05 UTC +00:00], ["tag_id", 5], ["taggable_id", 29], ["taggable_type", "Consumer"], ["tagger_id", nil], ["tagger_type", nil]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE ("taggings"."tag_id" = 6 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = 29 AND "taggings"."context" = 'tags' AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("context", "created_at", "tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "tagger_id", "tagger_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["context", "tags"], ["created_at", Fri, 15 Feb 2013 00:25:05 UTC +00:00], ["tag_id", 6], ["taggable_id", 29], ["taggable_type", "Consumer"], ["tagger_id", nil], ["tagger_type", nil]]
   (11.9ms)  COMMIT
 => true
1.9.3p286 :007 > Consumer.first.tags
  Consumer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "consumers".* FROM "consumers" LIMIT 1
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = 30 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Consumer' AND (taggings.context = 'tags')
 => []
```

Also, I can't find tags or taggings as a table in my DB. Thanks for helping me to understand this.

EDIT:

I think I see the problem.. in the taggings table I am seeing id, tag_id, taggable_id, taggable_type, tagger_id, tagger_type, context columns.. the rows seem complete with the exception of tagger_id and tagger_type. Do you think this has anything to do with the tags not being associated with the consumer's id?  I guess the question is, where should the Consumer.id actually be appearing in the taggings table.. At the moment the Consumer.first.id is not in any of the columns in taggings! The Consumer.first.id == 30

[image]

Comment: your tagging table looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

try appending to the array of the tags_list via

```
@consumer.tag_list << "foo"
@consumber.save
```

then save

Also acts_as_taggable_on does create a tabled called tags in your case. You may want to run a migration if your not seeing it.

Comment: do you have acts_as_taggable in your Consumer model?

Comment: Yes,   acts_as_taggable_on :tags

Comment: whats your tags table look like?

Comment: Well, this is interesting.. it works fine from a view.. but not from the console.. When I followed the rails cast all worked as expected.. Not sure I get it, but meh. http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?autoplay=true

Comment: With a <%= f.input :tag_list %>

Comment: I mean in console where you are having issues.

Comment: I tried as you suggested above, but read my console above for the other way I tried